# Recompile VIM with Python support for clang_complete

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, clang-complete

I've been googling this for about an hour now, with alot of people having the same question, although I cannot seem to get my answer.  I am trying to make get clang_complete to work, and I know I need Python support in Vim.  My compilation of Vim, according to `:version` , is missing `-python` and `-python3`.  Simple question: on Linux Debian, how can I recompile Vim with python support?

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk` should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install python3-dev ppkg first.

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

and after that compile vim from sources

`./configure --enable-python3interp=dynamic && make && make install`

Now you have vim with python3 suppport as dynamic load lib.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the python interpretor, try

```
./configure --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-python3interp=yes && make && make install
```

You can get a list of features and packages by looking into `src/auto/configure`. Here's the one from my [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) version `7.4`.

```
Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-fail-if-missing    Fail if dependencies on additional features
     specified on the command line are missing.
  --disable-darwin        Disable Darwin (Mac OS X) support.
  --disable-selinux   Don't check for SELinux support.
  --disable-xsmp          Disable XSMP session management
  --disable-xsmp-interact Disable XSMP interaction
  --enable-luainterp=OPTS     Include Lua interpreter.  default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-mzschemeinterp   Include MzScheme interpreter.
  --enable-perlinterp=OPTS     Include Perl interpreter.  default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-pythoninterp=OPTS   Include Python interpreter. default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-python3interp=OPTS   Include Python3 interpreter. default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-tclinterp      Include Tcl interpreter.
  --enable-rubyinterp=OPTS     Include Ruby interpreter.  default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-cscope         Include cscope interface.
  --enable-workshop       Include Sun Visual Workshop support.
  --disable-netbeans      Disable NetBeans integration support.
  --enable-sniff          Include Sniff interface.
  --enable-multibyte      Include multibyte editing support.
  --enable-hangulinput    Include Hangul input support.
  --enable-xim            Include XIM input support.
  --enable-fontset        Include X fontset output support.
  --enable-gui=OPTS     X11 GUI default=auto OPTS=auto/no/gtk2/gnome2/motif/athena/neXtaw/photon/carbon
  --enable-gtk2-check     If auto-select GUI, check for GTK+ 2 default=yes
  --enable-gnome-check    If GTK GUI, check for GNOME default=no
  --enable-motif-check    If auto-select GUI, check for Motif default=yes
  --enable-athena-check   If auto-select GUI, check for Athena default=yes
  --enable-nextaw-check   If auto-select GUI, check for neXtaw default=yes
  --enable-carbon-check   If auto-select GUI, check for Carbon default=yes
  --disable-gtktest       Do not try to compile and run a test GTK program
  --disable-largefile     omit support for large files
  --disable-acl           Don't check for ACL support.
  --disable-gpm           Don't use gpm (Linux mouse daemon).
  --disable-sysmouse    Don't use sysmouse (mouse in *BSD console).
  --disable-nls           Don't support NLS (gettext()).

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-mac-arch=ARCH    current, intel, ppc or both
  --with-developer-dir=PATH    use PATH as location for Xcode developer tools
  --with-local-dir=PATH   search PATH instead of /usr/local for local libraries.
  --without-local-dir     do not search /usr/local for local libraries.
  --with-vim-name=NAME    what to call the Vim executable
  --with-ex-name=NAME     what to call the Ex executable
  --with-view-name=NAME   what to call the View executable
  --with-global-runtime=DIR    global runtime directory in 'runtimepath'
  --with-modified-by=NAME       name of who modified a release version
  --with-features=TYPE    tiny, small, normal, big or huge (default: normal)
  --with-compiledby=NAME  name to show in :version message
  --with-lua-prefix=PFX   Prefix where Lua is installed.
  --with-luajit           Link with LuaJIT instead of Lua.
  --with-plthome=PLTHOME   Use PLTHOME.
  --with-python-config-dir=PATH  Python's config directory
  --with-python3-config-dir=PATH  Python's config directory
  --with-tclsh=PATH       which tclsh to use (default: tclsh8.0)
  --with-ruby-command=RUBY  name of the Ruby command (default: ruby)
  --with-x                use the X Window System
  --with-gnome-includes=DIR Specify location of GNOME headers
  --with-gnome-libs=DIR   Specify location of GNOME libs
  --with-gnome            Specify prefix for GNOME files
  --with-motif-lib=STRING   Library for Motif
  --with-tlib=library     terminal library to be used
```

Comment: I have no such directory src/auto/configure, I did not build vim manually but rather pulled it via apt-get (debian respository).

Answer (score 0):

Very old question I know!

As you have asked for Debian: There is and has always been a vim-nox package around and `apt-cache show vim-nox` states:

*This package contains a version of vim compiled with support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python 3, Ruby, and Tcl but no GUI*.

Hence `apt install vim-nox` will provide `+python3` support needed by clang_complete  and there is no need to compile it yourself at all.

Just keep your `~/.vimrc` updated and make sure to
set the right library path there as clang major versions change quite frequently.

`let g:clang_library_path='/lib/llvm-14/lib/libclang.so.1'`