# VIM YouCompleteMe error serching py librarys

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

i was installing YCM in VIM and got this error:

`Searching Python 3.8 libraries... ERROR: Python headers are missing in /usr/include/python3.8`

i have tried with py 3.8 3.7 and 3.9 and the same is ouputing.

Some help would be appriciated(did i speel it right?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recompile VIM with Python support for clang\_complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081437/recompile-vim-with-python-support-for-clang-complete)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+Python+headers+are+missing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. You just need to install the python3-dev package.